# Dijkstra linear running time on dense graph with Binary Heap

Tags: algorithm, big-o, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

**First**: The general running time of Dijkstras Shortest Path algorithm is

[image: Dijkstra generalrunning time]

where m is the number of edges and n the number of vertices

**Second**: the number of expected decreasekey operations is the following

[image: expected running time]

**Third**: The expected running time of dijkstra with a binary Heap which allows all operations in log(n) time is

[image: expected binary heap]

But why is the running time on dense graphs linear if we consider a graph dense if
[image: dense graph]

Can someone help with the O-notation and log calculations here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution is now the following

[image: calcu]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First it isn't hard to show that if `m` is big omega of `n log(n) log(log(n))` then `log(n)` is big omega of `log(m)`.  Therefore you can show that `m` is big omega of `n log(m) log(log(m))`.

From this you can show that `n` is big omega of `m / (log(m) log(log(m)))`.

Substitute this back into the expression you have in the third point and we get that the expected running time is:

```
O(m + n log(m/n) log(n))

                   m                                                 m
    = O(m + (------------------) log(log(m) log(log(m))) log(------------------)
             log(m) log(log(m))                              log(m) log(log(m))
```

From here you can expand all of the logs of products into sums of logs.  You'll get a lot of terms.  And then it is just a question of demonstrating that every one is `O(m)` or `o(m)`.  Which is straightforward, though tedious.